# Sax - ExpatParser$ParseException

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I'm making an Android application that reads an XML Internet. This application uses SAX to parse XML. This is my code for the part of parsing:

```
public LectorSAX(String url){
    try{
        SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        DefaultHandler lxmlr=new LibraryXMLReader() ;
        sp.parse(url, lxmlr);

        nodo=((LibraryXMLReader)lxmlr).getNodoActual();

    }catch(ParserConfigurationException e){ 
        System.err.println("Error de parseo en LectorSAX.java: "+e);
    }catch(SAXException e){
        System.err.println("Error de sax LectorSAX.java: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Error de  io LectorSAX.java: " + e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that SAXException occurs. The exception message is as follows:

> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 4, column
>   42: not well-formed (invalid token)

However, if I put the same code in a normal Java SE application, this exception does not occur and everything works fine.

Why the same code works fine in a Java SE application, not an Android?. On the other hand, How to solve the problem?.

Thanks for the help.

Greetings.

Comment: Can u share ur xml ... and as per error there is a problem with ur xml ..

Comment: @MohitSharma But, why the same code works fine in a Java SE application, not an Android?. This is the URL: http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_33002.xml

Comment: original i thought that there is some problem with ur xml as per error .. but its not like that ... now only solution with u is that u have debug the parsing

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with the encoding ? Do you use UTF-8 ? I don't know the specifics of Android.

Comment: @Ikuti I have not specified encoding. I have not specified encoding. Is it necessary in Android?, It seems that Java is not required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be a character encoding problem.
As you can see, the invalid token error points to the line #4.
In this line, you can find an acute (*Meteorología*) and a tilde (*España*).
The XML header shows a **ISO-8859-15** encoding value. As it's less common than UTFs or ISO-8859-1 encodings, this could result in a error when the SAXParser connects and try to convert the byte content into chars using your system default charset.

Then, you'll need to tell the SAXParser which charset to use. A way to do so, is to pass an [InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html), instead of the URL, to the parse method. As an example:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

InputSource is = new InputSource(url);
is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-15");

DefaultHandler lxmlr=new LibraryXMLReader() ;
sp.parse(is, lxmlr);
```

**EDIT:**
It seems that Android VM does not support this encoding, throwing a `org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: unknown encoding` exception.
As ISO-8859-15 it's mainly compatible with ISO-8859-1, except some specific characters (as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)), a workaround is changing the `ISO-8859-15` value to `ISO-8859-1` at the setEncoding method, forcing the parser to use a different but compatible charset encoding:

```
is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

As it seems, as Android doesn't support the declared charset, it uses its default (UTF-8) and hence the parser can't use the XML declaration to choose the apropiate encoding.

Comment: Hi @tomas-narros, thanks, I'll try and you'll notice the result.

Comment: Shouldn't the parser precicely use the XML declaration to choose the appropriate encoding?

Comment: That's a good point @JB. For sure it should. But I'm pretty sure that this is a encoding problem.

Comment: Hi @TomasNarros,I tried with the encoding you told me, but I get the following error:

Error de sax LectorSAX.java: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: unknown encoding

Comment: @Lobo: Okay. It seems that Android VM does not support this encoding. As ISO-8859-15 it's mainly compatible with ISO-8859-1, except some specific characters (as you can see at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15), i would try changing the ISO-8859-15 value to ISO-8859-1 at the setEncoding method. It seems that as long as you Android doesn't support the charset, it's using its default (UTF-8) and hence the parser can't use the XML declaration to choose the apropiate encoding. Please, check and tell me if it worked

Comment: @Lobo: I'm glad to hear it. I will update the full answer to make the solution available at it for future references.

Comment: @TomasNarros I am using XML parser. In that Xml.parse() method do not supports `InputSource`. In this case, any idea?